# Configuring Spring Security JWT authentication using OAuth2 resource server results in strange behavior

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I have been developing Spring Boot App and implemented Spring Security JWT authentication using OAuth2 resource server, but here seems to be some issue with my configuration. Whenever I try to login I get console log where I find the `Roles/Authorities` of current user (which is being logged) are omitted, other users `Roles/Authorities` are shown.

My details are `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.2'
}

group = 'com.crazy.coder'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server'
    // Solution to => Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.crypto.generators.SCrypt
    implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk18on:1.76'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

My entities are `User.java`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements UserDetails {

    private String username;
   @Size(max = 700)
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(
            cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE},
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER
    )
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> authorities = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    public User(){
    }

    public User(String username, String password, Set<Role> authorities) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setAuthorities(Set<Role> authorities) {
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return this.authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        if (!super.equals(o)) return false;
        User user = (User) o;
        return Objects.equals(username, user.username) && Objects.equals(password, user.password) && Objects.equals(authorities, user.authorities);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(super.hashCode(), username, password, authorities);
    }
}
```

`Role.java`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {

    private String authority;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authorities")
    private Set<User> users = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public Role(){
    }

    public Role(String authority) {
        this.authority = authority;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return this.authority;
    }

    public void setAuthority(String authority) {
        this.authority = authority;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        if (!super.equals(o)) return false;
        Role role = (Role) o;
        return Objects.equals(authority, role.authority) && Objects.equals(users, role.users);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(super.hashCode(), authority, users);
    }
}
```

Now I have configured `UserService` which implements `UserDetailsService` as:

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserService(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return userRepository.findByUsername(username).orElseThrow(
                () -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found")
        );
    }
}
```

Next I have `TokenService` which takes `Authentication` as an object and generates `jwt-token`:

```
@Service
public class TokenService {

    private final JwtEncoder jwtEncoder;

    private final JwtDecoder jwtDecoder;

    public TokenService(JwtEncoder jwtEncoder, JwtDecoder jwtDecoder) {
        this.jwtEncoder = jwtEncoder;
        this.jwtDecoder = jwtDecoder;
    }

    public String generateJwt(Authentication authentication){

        // Get current time
        var now = Instant.now();
        
        String scope = authentication.getAuthorities()
                .stream()
                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

        JwtClaimsSet claims = JwtClaimsSet.builder()
                .issuer("self")
                .issuedAt(now)
                .subject(authentication.getName())
                .claim("roles", scope)
                .build();

        return jwtEncoder.encode(JwtEncoderParameters.from(claims)).getTokenValue();
    }
}
```

Next I have `AuthService` as:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class AuthService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    private final RoleRepository roleRepository;

    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    private final TokenService tokenService;

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    public AuthService(
            UserRepository userRepository,
            RoleRepository roleRepository,
            PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,
            AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
            TokenService tokenService,
            UserDetailsService userDetailsService
    ) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.tokenService = tokenService;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    public User registerUser(String username, String password){

        // Encode password
        var encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password);

        // GET AUTHORITIES
        var userRole = roleRepository.findByAuthority("USER").orElseThrow(
                () -> new EntityNotFoundException("Invalid role")
        );

        var roles = new LinkedHashSet<Role>();
        roles.add(userRole);

        return userRepository.save(
                new User(username,encodedPassword, roles)
        );

    }


    public LoginDTO loginUser(String username, String password){

        try{
            Authentication auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password)
            );

            String token = tokenService.generateJwt(auth);

            return new LoginDTO(userRepository.findByUsername(username).get(), token);

        } catch(AuthenticationException e){
            return new LoginDTO(null, "");
        }
    }

}
```

For key generation there are:

```
public class KeyGeneratorUtility {

    public static KeyPair generateRSAKey(){
        KeyPair keyPair;

        try {
            var keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);

            // Set KeyPair
            keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        } catch (Exception e){
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }

        return keyPair;
    }

}
```

and

```
@Component
public class RSAKeyProperties {

    private RSAPublicKey rsaPublicKey;
    private RSAPrivateKey rsaPrivateKey;

    public RSAKeyProperties() {
        var keyPair = KeyGeneratorUtility.generateRSAKey();
        this.rsaPublicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        this.rsaPrivateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
    }

    public RSAPublicKey getRsaPublicKey() {
        return this.rsaPublicKey;
    }

    public void setRsaPublicKey(RSAPublicKey rsaPublicKey) {
        this.rsaPublicKey = rsaPublicKey;
    }

    public RSAPrivateKey getRsaPrivateKey() {
        return this.rsaPrivateKey;
    }

    public void setRsaPrivateKey(RSAPrivateKey rsaPrivateKey) {
        this.rsaPrivateKey = rsaPrivateKey;
    }
}
```

with all above finally I have `SecurityConfiguration` as:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private static final String BASE_PATH = "/api/v1";

    private final RSAKeyProperties keys;

    public SecurityConfiguration(RSAKeyProperties keys) {
        this.keys = keys;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
        // FIX for error -> Refused to display 'http://localhost:8080/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.
        http.headers( headers ->
            headers.frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::sameOrigin)
        );

        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests( auths -> {
                   auths
                           .requestMatchers(antMatcher(BASE_PATH +"/auth/**")).permitAll()
                           .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/h2-console/**")).permitAll()
                           .requestMatchers(antMatcher(BASE_PATH + "/admin/**")).hasRole("ADMIN")
                           .anyRequest().authenticated();
                });
        // Set OAuth2
        http.oauth2ResourceServer(
                resourceServerConfigurer -> {
                    resourceServerConfigurer.jwt(
                            jwt -> {
                                jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter());
                            }
                    );
                }
        ).sessionManagement(
                sessionManagementConfigurer -> {
                    sessionManagementConfigurer.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
                }
        );

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(UserDetailsService userDetailsService){
        var authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider(passwordEncoder());
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return new ProviderManager(authProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new SCryptPasswordEncoder(16384, 8, 2, 64, 128);

    }

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(){
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(keys.getRsaPublicKey()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtEncoder jwtEncoder(){
        JWK jwk = new RSAKey.Builder(keys.getRsaPublicKey()).privateKey(keys.getRsaPrivateKey()).build();
        JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwks = new ImmutableJWKSet<>(new JWKSet(jwk));

        return new NimbusJwtEncoder(jwks);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter(){
        JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
        jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthoritiesClaimName("roles");
        jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix("ROLE_");

        JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter);

        return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
    }
}
```

Now controller is:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1/auth")
public class AuthController {

    private final AuthService authService;

    public AuthController(AuthService authService) {
        this.authService = authService;
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/register")
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@RequestBody RegisterDTO registerDTO){
        var currentUser = authService.registerUser(registerDTO.username(), registerDTO.password());

        return ResponseEntity.ok(
                currentUser
        );
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(@RequestBody RegisterDTO registerDTO){
        var currentUser = authService.loginUser(registerDTO.username(), registerDTO.password());

        return ResponseEntity.ok(
                currentUser
        );
    }
}
```

With all code given above when make register request:

```
###
POST http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/register
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "username": "crazy_coder",
  "password": "crazy_password"
}
```

I get response as:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 15 Aug 2023 13:50:15 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Connection: keep-alive

{
  "id": 3,
  "username": "crazy_coder",
  "authorities": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "authority": "USER"
    }
  ],
  "enabled": true,
  "accountNonLocked": true,
  "accountNonExpired": true,
  "credentialsNonExpired": true
}
```

and console logs are:

```
Hibernate: insert into users (password,username,id) values (?,?,?)
2023-08-15 18:50:16,508 DEBUG org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.mutation : Inserting collection rows - com.crazy.coder.auth.model.User.authorities : 3
2023-08-15 18:50:16,508 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL : insert into user_roles (user_id,role_id) values (?,?)
Hibernate: insert into roles (user_id,role_id) values (?,?)
2023-08-15 18:50:16,510 DEBUG org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.mutation : Done inserting `1` collection rows : com.crazy.coder.auth.model.User.authorities
```

Now that said when I login using same username and password:

```
###
POST http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/login
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "username": "crazy_coder",
  "password": "crazy_password"
}
```

I get response empty authorities collection as:

```
{
  "user": {
    "id": 3,
    "username": "crazy_coder",
    "authorities": [],
    "enabled": true,
    "accountNonLocked": true,
    "accountNonExpired": true,
    "credentialsNonExpired": true,
  },
  "jwtToken": "eyJ...J9.....kg"
}
```

but when I see the console log, I see only authorities collection of current user is empty but other users authorities collection is fetched fine as shown:

```
2023-08-15 19:01:54,875 DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter : Listing entities:
2023-08-15 19:01:54,876 DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter : com.crazy.coder.auth.model.Role{authority=USER, users=[], id=2}
2023-08-15 19:01:54,876 DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter : com.crazy.coder.auth.model.Role{authority=ADMIN, users=[com.crazy.coder.auth.model.User#2], id=1}
2023-08-15 19:01:54,876 DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter : com.crazy.coder.auth.model.User{id=3, authorities=[], username=crazy_coder}
2023-08-15 19:01:54,876 DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter : com.crazy.coder.auth.model.User{id=1, authorities=[com.crazy.coder.auth.model.Role#2], username=crazy_coder_user}
2023-08-15 19:01:54,876 DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter : com.crazy.coder.auth.model.User{ id=2, authorities=[], username=crazy_coder_admin}
```

I requested with `crazy_coder` and got:

```
2023-08-15 19:01:54,876 DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter : com.crazy.coder.auth.model.User{id=3, authorities=[], username=crazy_coder}
```

but other users saved are:

```
2023-08-15 19:01:54,876 DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter : com.crazy.coder.auth.model.User{id=1, authorities=[com.crazy.coder.auth.model.Role#2], username=crazy_coder_user}
2023-08-15 19:01:54,876 DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter : com.crazy.coder.auth.model.User{ id=2, authorities=[], username=crazy_coder_admin}
```

at line

```
2023-08-15 19:01:54,876 DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter : com.crazy.coder.auth.model.User{id=1, authorities=[com.crazy.coder.auth.model.Role#2], username=crazy_coder_user}
```

I get `authorities=[com.crazy.coder.auth.model.Role#2]`, but when I login using `crazy_coder_admin` user name I get console log:

```
2023-08-15 19:14:28,992 DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter : Listing entities:
2023-08-15 19:14:28,992 DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter : com.crazy.coder.auth.model.Role{authority=USER, users=[], id=2}
2023-08-15 19:14:28,992 DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter : com.crazy.coder.auth.model.Role{authority=ADMIN, users=[com.crazy.coder.auth.model.User#2], id=1}
2023-08-15 19:14:28,992 DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter : com.crazy.coder.auth.model.User{id=3, authorities=[com.crazy.coder.auth.model.Role#2], username=crazy_coder}
2023-08-15 19:14:28,992 DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter : com.crazy.coder.auth.model.User{id=1, authorities=[com.crazy.coder.auth.model.Role#2], username=crazy_coder_user}
2023-08-15 19:14:28,993 DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter : com.crazy.coder.auth.model.User{id=2, authorities=[], username=crazy_coder_admin}
```

You can see I get `Roles/Authorities` collection for all as shown below:

```
 2023-08-15 19:14:28,992 DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter : com.crazy.coder.auth.model.User{id=3, authorities=[com.crazy.coder.auth.model.Role#2], username=crazy_coder}
    2023-08-15 19:14:28,992 DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter : com.crazy.coder.auth.model.User{id=1, authorities=[com.crazy.coder.auth.model.Role#2], username=crazy_coder_user}
```

but `Roles/Authorities` collection for `crazy_coder_admin` is never fetched:

```
2023-08-15 19:14:28,993 DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter : com.crazy.coder.auth.model.User{id=2, authorities=[], username=crazy_coder_admin}
```

Did I miss something, where did I make mistake to configure all this correctly.

Please help me in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This entire implementation is faulty, you have built an application that logs in a user and directly creates and issues a jwt as a session token. JWTs should NOT be used as a session, its a huge security risk giving out jwts directly to clients and that is why you have had to write all this code because spring security knows that and thats why they dont have an implementation for it. A correctly implemented oauth2 flow using jwts, will never issue a token to the client instead give the client access tokens in form of a cookie with the httponly flag set.

Comment: In your case read spring security docs, give up using jwts and instead implement FormLogin or if you MUST use jwts use a correct auth server issuer like spring authentication server, keycloak, curity, google, facebook, auth0 and then use a BFF that will fetch the token and issue a cookie to the client and then implement a proxy that will exchange the cookie for a jwt that is only used internally between the microservices. Dont give out jwts to the webclient, just DONT

Comment: @Toerktumlare thanks taking time to go through my question, I really appreciate your criticism and better security flow, but I want to clear it that this is just a practice project and I just wanted to get stared with OAuth2, I have been following [YT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TeBt0Ike_Tk) video and everything works fine in that tutorial, but I get this strange behavior!

Comment: That tutorial is bad, and he himself even admits that he has only watched other bad tutorials. Notice how he never says that he actually read the official documentation. He is basing his knowledge off other bad tutorials. Its what is called an echo chamber. He does not know how security works and i suggest you read the docs instead of following his tutorial that is also very bad.